# iscroll childbrowser maximum width

Tags: ipad, cordova, ios6, iscroll, childbrowser

just a questition related to Apple IOS6/IPad 2/IPad Mini and an iScroll 4.2.5 within a Childbrowser which is opened through an App build in Adobe Phonegap 2.3.0:

Horizontal Scroller with Images, scaled to 100% of the device height (width is dynamic):

```
<div id="iscroller">
<table><tr>
<td><img src="image1.jpg" /></td>
<td><img src="image2.jpg" /></td>
...
</tr></table>
</div>
```

one Image has a width of 1125px with some borders and spaces around the iscroller with 80 pages goes up to the estimated width of 111966

The iscroll works perfect for horizontal scrolling. But if there are more than 80 Images within the scroller, IPad 2 stopps displaying Images after the 42th Image, the IPad Mini stopps displaying after the 70th Image. It seems that the last Image is "cutted" of from top to bottom or the page's end has reached for the Images but not for the scroller.

It seems that there is a maximum width, but what now?
tnx

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to only show the number of allowed images and then refresh the iscroll with the next amount of allowable images.

Comment: Thanxs, i have used a paging for this